# How to integrate composer into my custom framework

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, composer-php

Okay I have googled everywhere but find not much help regarding integrating  composer. I am making my very first php mvc framework. I want composer functionality like i found in laravel. I need workflow of the composer and how to integrate it into my mvc.
Thanks

Comment: Composer is a tool and not Laravel specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initial steps:

- run `composer init` to initialize composer,
- in your main file (usually `index.php`) add `require ('vendor/autoload.php');`
- in your `composer.json` add autoload section for example:

  ```
  "autoload": {
     "psr-4": {
        "model\\": "model/"
     }
  },
  ```
- run `composer install`

This is basic setup. Now if you need any extra dependencies, add them into `require` section and run again `composer install` to install them.

Answer (score 1):

What type of composer functionality do you want or need?
If you want to use vendor packages as your dependencies, install composer. Then create a **composer.json** file and follow this syntax:

```
{
   "require": {
      "vendor/package": "dev-master or whatever version you need"
   }
}
```

All the registered packages you can find at [Composer's package manager called Packagist](http://packagist.org).
When you are done, locate your folder and run `composer install` from the command prompt.